# how to solve TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in simple node project?

Tags: node.js

im trying to create a simple address book,

```
//globol object for contacts database
// Business Logic for AddressBook ---------
function AddressBook(contacts) {
    this.contacts = [];
}

AddressBook.prototype.addContact = (contact) => {
    this.contacts.push(contact);
}

// Business Logic for Contacts ---------
function Contact(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName,
        this.lastName = lastName,
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
}

Contact.prototype.fullName = () => {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

var addressBook = new AddressBook();
var contact = new Contact("Ada", "Lovelace", "503-555-0100");
var contact2 = new Contact("Grace", "Hopper", "503-555-0199");
addressBook.addContact(contact);
addressBook.addContact(contact2);

console.log(addressBook.contacts);
```

but it prints the error

.../addressBook.js:8
    this.contacts.push(contact);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at AddressBook.addContact (/home/maku/Documents/epicodus/addressBook.js:8:19)
    at Object. (/home/maku/Documents/epicodus/addressBook.js:25:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the arrow function [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

If you use arrow functions, `this` won't be bound to the current instance. You need to create functions with the keyword `function` :

```js
function AddressBook(contacts) {
    this.contacts = [];
}

AddressBook.prototype.addContact = function(contact) {
    this.contacts.push(contact);
}

// Business Logic for Contacts ---------
function Contact(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName,
        this.lastName = lastName,
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
}

Contact.prototype.fullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

var addressBook = new AddressBook();
var contact = new Contact("Ada", "Lovelace", "503-555-0100");
var contact2 = new Contact("Grace", "Hopper", "503-555-0199");
addressBook.addContact(contact);
addressBook.addContact(contact2);

console.log(addressBook.contacts);
```

Comment: Though, how do u know when **NOT** to use arrow functions? [Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8879527/rahul-sharma)

Comment: You don't want to use arrow functions when you don't need to keep `this` bound to the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function changes the scope of the 'this' keyword, in your addContact method, change the method to a function declaration and it'll remove the error